# How to show Vee validate all errors for one field

Tags: vue.js

I want to see all errors for one field. But it always show me the first one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GjSG.png)

Comment: my code is like this:<div class="form-group"  :class="{ 'has-error': errors.has('password') }">
              <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
              <input v-validate="'required|min:3'" type="password" v-model="password"  class="form-control"
                name="password" placeholder="Password">
              <span v-show="true" class="help-block" v-for="er in errors.collect('password')">
                {{ er }}
              </span>
            </div>